# SecKeyCopyKeyExchangeResult() function return an error, "kSecKeyKeyExchangeParameterRequestedSize is missing"

Tags: security, xcode11, ecdh

I'm using Xcode11 Beta as IDE and Swift.

Below is my code, my code can work well on Xcode10.3, but it can't work on Xcode11. 
When I call the function SecKeyCopyKeyExchangeResult(), the stack always return an error, "kSecKeyKeyExchangeParameterRequestedSize is missing", but it's okay on Xcode10.3. 
I checked Apple Developer portal, haven't any clue on it.

`
    func main() {

```
    testECDH()
}

private func testECDH(){
    generateKeyPair()
    let alicePublicKey = getPublicKey()
    let alicePrivateKey = getPrivateKey()
    print(alicePublicKey)
    print(alicePrivateKey)

    generateKeyPair()
    let bobPublicKey = getPublicKey()
    let bobPrivateKey = getPrivateKey()
    print(bobPublicKey)
    print(bobPrivateKey)

    let alice_bob_ecdhsecret = ecdhSecretCalculation(publicKey: alicePublicKey, privateKey: bobPrivateKey)!
    let bob_alice_ecdhsecret = ecdhSecretCalculation(publicKey: bobPublicKey, privateKey: alicePrivateKey)!

    os_log("alice_bob_ecdhsecret = %@", alice_bob_ecdhsecret)
    os_log("bob_alice_ecdhsecret = %@", bob_alice_ecdhsecret)
}

private func generateKeyPair(){
    let attributes: [String: Any] = [kSecAttrKeySizeInBits as String: 256,
                                     kSecAttrKeyType as String: kSecAttrKeyTypeECSECPrimeRandom,
                                     kSecPrivateKeyAttrs as String: [kSecAttrIsPermanent as String: false],
                                     kSecPublicKeyAttrs as String:[kSecAttrIsPermanent as String: false]]

    var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?

    privateKey = SecKeyCreateRandomKey(attributes as CFDictionary, &error)!

    if privateKey != nil {
        publicKey = SecKeyCopyPublicKey(privateKey!)
    }


}

private func getPrivateKey()->SecKey{
    return privateKey!
}

private func getPublicKey()->SecKey{
    return publicKey!
}

private func ecdhSecretCalculation(publicKey: SecKey, privateKey: SecKey) -> NSData?
{
    var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?

    let keyPairAttr:[String : Any] = [kSecAttrKeySizeInBits as String: 256,
                                      kSecAttrKeyType as String: kSecAttrKeyTypeECSECPrimeRandom,
                                      kSecPrivateKeyAttrs as String: [kSecAttrIsPermanent as String: false],
                                      kSecPublicKeyAttrs as String:[kSecAttrIsPermanent as String: false]]
    let algorithm:SecKeyAlgorithm = SecKeyAlgorithm.ecdhKeyExchangeStandardX963SHA256//ecdhKeyExchangeStandardX963SHA256

    let shared:CFData? = SecKeyCopyKeyExchangeResult(privateKey, algorithm, publicKey, keyPairAttr as! CFDictionary, &error)

    return shared
}`
```

Answer (score 5):

I just solve this issue by below code snippet

```
let keyPairAttr:[String : Any] = [kSecAttrKeySizeInBits as String: 256,

                                      SecKeyKeyExchangeParameter.requestedSize.rawValue as String: 32,
                                      kSecAttrKeyType as String: kSecAttrKeyTypeECSECPrimeRandom,
                                      kSecPrivateKeyAttrs as String: [kSecAttrIsPermanent as String: false],
                                      kSecPublicKeyAttrs as String:[kSecAttrIsPermanent as String: false]]
    let algorithm:SecKeyAlgorithm = SecKeyAlgorithm.ecdhKeyExchangeStandardX963SHA256//ecdhKeyExchangeStandardX963SHA256

    let shared:CFData? = SecKeyCopyKeyExchangeResult(privateKey, algorithm, publicKey, keyPairAttr as! CFDictionary, &error)
```

Please noticed that below is the code I added to solve this issue:

```
SecKeyKeyExchangeParameter.requestedSize.rawValue as String: 32,
```

Comment: I still get this error even after your suggested changes... how did you solve? `keyPairAttr = ["requestedSize": 32, "private": ["perm": false], "bsiz": 256, "type": 73, "public": ["perm": false]]
Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-50 "kSecKeyKeyExchangeParameterRequestedSize is missing" UserInfo={NSDescription=kSecKeyKeyExchangeParameterRequestedSize is missing}`

Comment: How can i crypt and decrypt a message using this shared key?

Answer (score 0):

Just for convenience, here is the complete and corrected Kaiser Ren playground example (tested on Xcode 14.2 / Swift 5.7):

```swift
import Foundation
import Security

func generateKeyPair() -> (privateKey: SecKey, publicKey: SecKey)? {
    let attributes = [
        kSecAttrKeySizeInBits as String: 256,
        kSecAttrKeyType as String: kSecAttrKeyTypeECSECPrimeRandom,
        kSecPrivateKeyAttrs as String: [
            kSecAttrIsPermanent as String: false
        ],
        kSecPublicKeyAttrs as String: [
            kSecAttrIsPermanent as String: false
        ]
    ] as CFDictionary

    var cfError: Unmanaged<CFError>?

    guard let privateKey = SecKeyCreateRandomKey(attributes, &cfError) else {
        print("\n[\(#function)] Error generating private key, cause:\n\((cfError?.takeRetainedValue() as Error?)?.localizedDescription ?? "unknown")\n")

        return nil
    }

    guard let publicKey = SecKeyCopyPublicKey(privateKey) else {
        print("\n[\(#function)] Error generating public key, cause:\n\((cfError?.takeRetainedValue() as Error?)?.localizedDescription ?? "unknown")\n")

        return nil
    }

    return (privateKey: privateKey, publicKey: publicKey)
}

func ecdhSecretCalculation(publicKey: SecKey, privateKey: SecKey) -> Data? {
    let keyPairAttr = [
        kSecAttrKeySizeInBits as String: 256,
        SecKeyKeyExchangeParameter.requestedSize.rawValue as String: 32,
        kSecAttrKeyType as String: kSecAttrKeyTypeECSECPrimeRandom,
        kSecPrivateKeyAttrs as String: [
            kSecAttrIsPermanent as String: false
        ],
        kSecPublicKeyAttrs as String: [
            kSecAttrIsPermanent as String: false
        ]
    ] as CFDictionary

    let algorithm = SecKeyAlgorithm.ecdhKeyExchangeStandardX963SHA256//.ecdhKeyExchangeCofactorX963SHA256

    var cfError: Unmanaged<CFError>?

    guard let sharedSecret = SecKeyCopyKeyExchangeResult(privateKey, algorithm, publicKey, keyPairAttr, &cfError) else {
        print("\n[\(#function)] Error during ecdh secret calculation, cause:\n\((cfError?.takeRetainedValue() as Error?)?.localizedDescription ?? "unknown")\n")

        return nil
    }

    return sharedSecret as Data
}

extension Data {
    struct HexEncodingOptions: OptionSet {
        let rawValue: Int
        static let upperCase = HexEncodingOptions(rawValue: 1 << 0)
    }

    func hexEncodedString(options: HexEncodingOptions = []) -> String {
        let format = options.contains(.upperCase) ? "%02hhX" : "%02hhx"

        return self.map { String(format: format, $0) }.joined()
    }
}

func testEcdh() {
    if let (alicePrivateKey, alicePublicKey) = generateKeyPair(),
       let (bobPrivateKey, bobPublicKey) = generateKeyPair()
    {
        print("\nalicePrivateKey:\n\(alicePrivateKey)\n")
        print("\nalicePublicKey:\n\(alicePublicKey)\n")

        print("\nbobPrivateKey:\n\(bobPrivateKey)\n")
        print("\nbobPublicKey:\n\(bobPublicKey)\n")

        guard let aliceBobEcdhSecret = ecdhSecretCalculation(publicKey: alicePublicKey, privateKey: bobPrivateKey) else {
            return
        }

        let aliceBobEcdhSecretHex = aliceBobEcdhSecret.hexEncodedString()

        guard let bobAliceEcdhSecret = ecdhSecretCalculation(publicKey: bobPublicKey, privateKey: alicePrivateKey) else {
            return
        }

        let bobAliceEcdhsecretHex = bobAliceEcdhSecret.hexEncodedString()

        print("\nalice bob ecdh secret hex string: \(aliceBobEcdhSecretHex)\n")
        print("\nbob alice ecdh secret hex string: \(bobAliceEcdhsecretHex)\n")
        print("\naliceBobEcdhSecretHex == bobAliceEcdhsecretHex: \(aliceBobEcdhSecretHex == bobAliceEcdhsecretHex)\n")
    }
}

testEcdh()
```