# SecKeyCopyKeyExchangeResult does not work as nodejs ecdh in iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift

I have an application where I generate shared secret between iOS / android / nodejs using ECDH over secp521r1 curve. To ensure that it works I wrote a test that uses data generated with nodejs and that worked until iOS 13.

The source code of the test was:

```
let publicKey = "BABBvZ56c4bj1Zo73LIt/bBVa3jvGTA1fceoOG/M9TeXHx5ffCggRteEVS+bwrgQWPOwJPHhevNenaVn32ZnhztS0QFBqKGZTF1pKNSvuj+PDKQ625TauNroq+LQdeS+Pn6GVHL0iW5pp84NZ06L97VZ9HYm+g2lMnlUFV8hco2CmwBqHQ=="
let privateKey = "AXn994UN59QCEqmCmXmmNZ3hVZPlMwzTIeBupJGG4CqDWfWLuCTui7qiBfQtCFcQ1ks4NNB/tHEZUJ+bB97+pkJ3"
let otherBase64 = "BAAzWyzdh2e+ZNUCFt4oDADURb8+m9WA7gbWtTo57ZP3U23VuvMnRHf+12GpTSV8A5pt+vZfaR2cT02P+LPRc/kGzgAT2IYIgDz/cKbzMi520ZLa0GYk1xzCuNqFhdBZmrB5w0ymsPLdJzIG1QZ3xu7OufEipm5D41abphLLnbH+OyTX6w=="
let expectedShared = "AQkTOOHPcvlXufR2dm1FHaIJRlTgmxTJMI+h0kJ+nMVNopIP+opSqUNmflsgnJzT8JTodd/eehaaq5vvYdDVciIQ"

// iOS secKey is reconstructed by concatenating public and private key
let otherDataKey = Data.init(base64Encoded: otherBase64)!
var concatenatedKey = Data.init(base64Encoded: publicKey)!
concatenatedKey.append(Data.init(base64Encoded: privateKey)!)

// generate private key
var attributes: [String:Any] =
  [
    kSecAttrKeyClass as String: kSecAttrKeyClassPrivate,
    kSecAttrKeySizeInBits as String:      521,
    kSecAttrKeyType as String: kSecAttrKeyTypeECSECPrimeRandom,
]
var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
guard let secKey = SecKeyCreateWithData(concatenatedKey as CFData, attributes as CFDictionary, &error) else {
  XCTAssertTrue(false)
  return
}

// generate other public key
attributes[kSecAttrKeyClass as String] = kSecAttrKeyClassPublic
guard let otherKey = SecKeyCreateWithData(otherDataKey as CFData, attributes as CFDictionary, nil) else {
  XCTAssertTrue(false)
  return
}

// generate shared secret
let exchangeOptions: [String: Any] = [:]
guard let shared = SecKeyCopyKeyExchangeResult(secKey, SecKeyAlgorithm.ecdhKeyExchangeStandardX963SHA256, otherKey, exchangeOptions as CFDictionary, &error) else {
  XCTAssertTrue(false)
  return
}

// generate shared secret
XCTAssertEqual((shared as Data).base64EncodedString(), expectedShared);
```

With iOS 13 I was forced to modify the content of my exchangeOptions dictionary as discussed here ([SecKeyCopyKeyExchangeResult() function return an error, "kSecKeyKeyExchangeParameterRequestedSize is missing"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58007604/seckeycopykeyexchangeresult-function-return-an-error-kseckeykeyexchangeparam))

```
let exchangeOptions: [String: Any] = [SecKeyKeyExchangeParameter.requestedSize.rawValue as String: 66]
```

The problem is that with this option, the result of SecKeyCopyKeyExchangeResult does not match anymorewith nodejs one (which is also true on iOS 12)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found a solution... In iOS <= 12, leaving exchange parameters empty when trying to use ecdhKeyExchangeStandardX963SHA256 algorithm was falling back to using SecKeyAlgorithm.ecdhKeyExchangeCofactor.

Therefore the fix to reproduce previous behavior is to modify the SecKeyCopyKeyExchangeResult with

```
// generate shared secret
let exchangeOptions: [String: Any] = [:]
guard let shared = SecKeyCopyKeyExchangeResult(secKey, SecKeyAlgorithm.ecdhKeyExchangeCofactor, otherKey, exchangeOptions as CFDictionary, &error) else {
  XCTAssertTrue(false)
  return
}
```

This works at least for iOS 10 to 13

Comment: I can confirm that this solution work! We were searching for a fix since iOS 13 release, we were ready to throw the usage of Apple security frameworks to implement our Diffie Hellman implementation, we were going mad! thank you very much

Comment: thank you very much.  crazy that the function would just start producing different results :(

Comment: how do you use this shared to encrypt/decrypt the message?

Comment: @Fabiosoft The answer to that really depends on what you're trying to achieve and probably should be part of a whole new question. In short, I use the shared to get 48 random bytes (directly extracted or with HKDF depending on the context) then I use Common crypto to AES 256 encrypt/decrypt 32 bytes being the key and 16 being the IV

Comment: @MatthieuBouxin once I get the shared (data) how can I extract the SecKey to use? I cannot find any tutorial. I already created a new question but nobody can answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61091401/ios-swift-diffie-hellman-key-exchange-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-messages-using-sec